# Why function GetLastError returns 2?

Tags: winapi, rust, createfile

Today, I decided to practice by creating a simple program that creates a new file. But I got a problem that the file is not being created. How to solve this?

Firstly, I'm importing the required crate, then creating the `err()` function for printing errors after creating the file, if they will.

Secondly, I'm creating a function `to_u16()`, because `LPCWSTR` type needs `*const u16`.

Thirdly, I'm calling the `CreateFileW()` function for creating `file.rs`, and passing all necessary arguments (according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) and [this](https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/um/fileapi/fn.CreateFileW.html)).

createfile.rs

```
use winapi::shared::minwindef::DWORD;
use winapi::um::winnt;
use std::ffi::CString;
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi;
use winapi::ctypes::*;
use winapi::um::minwinbase::*;
use winapi::um::fileapi; 
use std::io;

fn err(){//print the last error
    unsafe{
        let xui =errhandlingapi::GetLastError();
        print!("{:?}",xui) ;// 2
    }
}

fn to_u16(s: &str) ->*const u16 {
    let c_str = CString::new(s).unwrap();
    c_str.as_ptr() as *const u16
}

fn main() {
    unsafe{
        let name:winnt::LPCWSTR =to_u16("file.rs") ; //lpFileName
        let acces:DWORD = winnt::GENERIC_WRITE; //dwDesiredAccess
        let share = winnt::FILE_SHARE_DELETE|winnt::FILE_SHARE_READ|winnt::FILE_SHARE_WRITE;//dwShareMode
        let security = 0 as *mut SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ;//lpSecurityAttributes
        let disposition = fileapi::OPEN_EXISTING; //dwCreationDisposition
        let atr = winnt::FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;//dwFlagsAndAttributes
        let handle = 0 as *mut c_void;//hTemplateFile

        fileapi::CreateFileW(name,acces,share,security,disposition,atr,handle);
        err();
        
    }
    
}
```

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "createfile"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html


[dependencies]
kernel32-sys = "0.2.2"

winapi = "0.3.9"

[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3.9", features = ["winuser", "fileapi", "errhandlingapi"] }
```

Comment: `to_u16()` returns a dangling pointer; the `CString` is destroyed when this function returns.

Comment: Q: *WHAT* is "errno 2"? A:  You can look in "errno.h", use the old "ErrMsg" tool (it used to ship with MSVS), or call [perror()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_perror.htm).  In this case, it means "File not found".  Since you called "fileapi::OPEN_EXISTING", you must 1) make sure the file already exists, and 2) exists in the directory path you're trying to open it from.  NOTE: if you're trying to "create" a brand new file ... then "OPEN_ALWAYS" might be a better choice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

Comment: The value returned by GetLastError() is meaningless unless the last function failed (and then only if it's documented as setting the error code in the event of failure). You're not checking if CreateFile succeeded or failed.

Comment: If you don't have any legacy code to maintain that uses it already, you shouldn't be using the [`winapi`](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) any longer. It's been dead for years now. The [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate is actively maintained (as is the [`windows-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crate, if you're looking for a raw API transliteration). If nothing else, it provides a convenient [`w!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/macro.w.html) macro that converts string literals into zero-terminated wide character string literals.

Answer (score 2):

Error 2 is [`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

You say you want to create a *new* file, but you are setting the `disposition` argument to `OPEN_EXISTING`, so if `file.rs` does not already exist then `CreateFileW()` will fail with this error.

Try using `CREATE_ALWAYS`, `CREATE_NEW`, or `OPEN_ALWAYS`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew):

> `[in] dwCreationDisposition`
>
> An action to take on a file or device that exists or does not exist.
>
> For devices other than files, this parameter is usually set to OPEN_EXISTING.
>
> For more information, see the Remarks section.
>
> This parameter must be one of the following values, which cannot be combined:
>
> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | CREATE_ALWAYS 2 | Creates a new file, always. If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). **If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero.** For more information, see the Remarks section of this topic. |
> | CREATE_NEW 1 | Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist. If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80). **If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created.** |
> | OPEN_ALWAYS 4 | Opens a file, always. If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). **If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero.** |
> | OPEN_EXISTING 3 | Opens a file or device, only if it exists. **If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).** For more information about devices, see the Remarks section. |
> | TRUNCATE_EXISTING 5 | Opens a file and truncates it so that its size is zero bytes, only if it exists. If the specified file does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2). The calling process must open the file with the GENERIC_WRITE bit set as part of the dwDesiredAccess parameter. |

Comment: Might want to note that `CreateFileW` has somewhat complex rules around when `GetLastError` will report meaningful values. The code in the question does not verify those conditions, and the value may well be meaningless.